# Different loss functions dependant on prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, loss-function

I'm working on a regression task to predict value y which is afterwards used for a classification (a, b or c).

```
If 0<y<5 --> class A
if 5<y<20 --> class B
if 20<y --> class C
```

It's quite hard for the learners to reach the values of y for class A compared to class B, because the "class size" is only 5 (0 to 5) compared to 15 (5 to 20). IMHO that means, that the predicted value y has to be more accurate in the range around 0 to 5 (or maybe 0 to 6 or 7) compared to the values around 8 to 17.

My idea is to build a custom loss functions that penalizes distances in the range of 0 to 5 (or 0 to 6 or 7) harder than in the range of 5 to 20. Is that possible?

Or does anyone have a better idea for addressing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can define hard penalty on class A more then class B, in this case if learner made a mistake for class a, then its penalizes more then mistake for class b.
for example you can define weight .8 for mistake of a, 0.1 for class b and 0.1 for class c, in this scenario, if learner made a mistake for class a , then loss is very big, and for this reason, learner can learn class a very good.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you maybe specify your idea? I am doing a regression on value y and use MSE loss now. How can I penalise class A? Where do I define this weight of e.g. 0.8 for class a?